# How to get the max row number per group/partition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2005. I have a payments table with payment id's, user id's, and timestamps. I want to find the most recent payment for each user. This is easy to search and find an answer for. What I also want to know though is if the most recent payment is the user's first payment or not.

I have the following which will number each user's payments:

```
SELECT
    p.payment_id,
    p.user_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.user_id ORDER BY p.payment_date) AS paymentNumber
FROM
    payment p
```

I'm not making the mental leap which then lets me then pick the highest paymentNumber per user. If I use the above as a subselect by using MAX(paymentNumber) and then grouping by user_id, I lose the payment_id which I need. But if I also add the payment_id into the group by clause, I'm back to one row per payment. I'm sure I'm overlooking the obvious. Any help?

Comment: is there a primary key on the table at all?

Comment: The primary key is payment_id.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*, CASE WHEN totalPayments>1 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END IsFirstPayment
  FROM(
                SELECT  p.payment_id,     
                                p.user_id,     
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.user_id ORDER BY p.payment_date DESC) AS paymentNumber,
                                SUM(1) OVER (PARTITION BY p.user_id) AS totalPayments
                    FROM payment p 
            ) a
WHERE   paymentNumber = 1
```

Comment: Why use SUM(1) when there is `COUNT(*) ` ??

Comment: `Count(*)` would be faster, gut feel. It doesn't even need to inspect records, just index length. Sum(1) has to make up the value 1 for each row and tally it.  You wouldn't normally write `select sum(1) from tbl` just to count records would you?

Comment: This works well for me in my initial tests. I'd definitely be curious to learn more about the performance issues of either way though.

Comment: An explanation of what you're doing in the "try this" code would be of great help

Answer (score 18):

Do the same thing again.

```
SELECT
    p.payment_id,
    p.user_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.user_id ORDER BY p.payment_date) AS paymentNumber,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.user_id ORDER BY p.payment_date DESC) AS reversePaymentNumber,
FROM
    payment p
```

Now the most recent payment has reversePaymentNumber 1, and the number of payments will be paymentNumber.

Comment: Your answer helped me select groups of rows with more than 1 rows in the partition. I summed the row number and the reverse row number and selected rows where the sum was greater than 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The query provided by OP does most of the work. All we need to do is change the `ORDER BY` clause provided to `ROW_NUMBER()` to descending at which point the most recent record will have a value of 1. I'm choosing to use a CTE as a matter of personal preference - a subquery would also be fine.

```sql
with cte as (
    SELECT
        p.payment_id,
        p.user_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY p.user_id
           ORDER BY p.payment_date desc
        ) AS paymentNumber
    FROM
        payment p
    )
select * from cte where paymentNumber = 1
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation and/or relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1):

a less cool way i suppose

```
; with maxp as
(
    select
        p.user_id,
        max(p.payment_date) as MaxPaymentDate
    from payment p
    group by p.userid
),
nump as
(
    select
        p.payment_id,     
        p.user_id,     
        p.payment_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.user_id ORDER BY p.payment_date) AS paymentNumber 
    FROM payment p
),
a as
(
select
    nump.payment_id,
    nump.user_id,
    nump.paymentNumber
    case when maxp.MaxPaymentDate is null then 'Old' else 'New' end as NewState
from nump
    left outer join maxp
        on nump.user_id=maxp.user_id
            and nump.payment_date=maxp.MaxPaymentDate
)

select
*
from a
where NewState='New'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OS.ContactId ORDER BY OS.Date ASC) AS FirstRow#,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OS.ContactId ORDER BY OS.Date DESC) AS LastRow#,
        OS.Contactid,CONVERT(VARCHAR,OS.Date,106) 'Purchase Month',
        OS.ProductId 'MyCII Subscription/Directory', OS.Charges 'Amount(INR)',OS.Date 'RAWDate'
        FROM tblOnlineServices OS
        WHERE Date IS NOT NULL AND Contactid IN('C000013112','C000010859') 
    ) FirstPurchase 
    WHERE FirstRow# = 1 OR LastRow# = 1
    ORDER BY Contactid, RAWDate
```

Answer (score -2):

How about this?

```
SELECT
    p.user_id,
    MAX(p.payment_date) as lastPayment,
    CASE COUNT(p.payment_id) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as isFirstPayment
FROM
    payment p
GROUP BY
    p.user_id
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have boolean datatypes `COUNT(p.payment_id) = 1` would need to be a `case` expression.

Comment: Also, I need the payment_id as output. Like I said in the original question, if you put that in the output and the group by clause, you then get a row for every payment, not just the latest.